# F# integer file directive

Tags: f#, fsyacc, fslex, fsc

I've been using fslex and fsyacc, and the F# source files (`.fs` they generate from the lexer (`.fsl`) and parser (`.fsp`) rules refer to the original `.fsl` (and sometimes to the same `.fs` source file) all over the place with statement such as this (numbers are line numbers):

```
lex.fs
1      # 1 "/[PROJECT-PATH-HERE]/lex.fsp
...
16     # 16 "/PROJECT-PATH-HERE]/lex.fs
17     // This is the type of tokens accepted by the parser
18     type token =
19       | EOF
...
```

Also, the `.fs` files generated by `pars.fsp` do the same kind of thing, but additionaly reference to the F# signature file (`.fsi`) generated alongside it. What does any of this do/mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The annotations you see in the generated code are [F# Compiler Directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233195.aspx) (specifically, the 'line' directive).

The 'line' directive makes it so that when the F# compiler needs to emit a warning/error message for some part of the generated code, it has a way to determine which part of the *original* file corresponds to that part of the generated code. In other words, the F# compiler can generate a warning/error message referencing the original code which is the basis of the generated code causing the error.